# OpenCV Python, reading video from named-pipe

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

I am trying to achieve results as shown on the video (Method 3 using netcat) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYGdge3T30o
It is to stream video from raspberry pi to PC and process it using openCV and python.

I use command

```
raspivid -vf -n -w 640 -h 480 -o - -t 0 -b 2000000 | nc 192.168.1.137 8000
```

to stream the video to my PC and then on the PC I created name pipe 'fifo' and redirected the output

```
nc -l -p 8000 -v > fifo
```

then i am trying to read the pipe and display the result in the python script

```
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy

FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-i', 'fifo',             # fifo is the named pipe
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',      # opencv requires bgr24 pixel format.
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-an','-sn',              # we want to disable audio processing (there is no audio)
        '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']    
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(640*480*3)
    # transform the byte read into a numpy array
    image =  numpy.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
    image = image.reshape((480,640,3))          # Notice how height is specified first and then width
    if image is not None:
        cv2.imshow('Video', image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    pipe.stdout.flush()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\python video stream\stream.py", line 19, in <module>
    image = image.reshape((480,640,3))          # Notice how height is specified first and then width
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (480,640,3)
```

It seems that the numpy array is empty, so any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try adding the full path to `ffmpeg.exe` including the directory.

Comment: From your post, it looks like `pipe.stdout.flush()` is inside the `while` loop. Is it a copy and paste problem, or is it inside the loop?

Comment: @Rotem  There will be the same error as mentioned above whether it is inside the loop or outside the loop

Comment: @Mark Setchell There will be a 'FileNotFoundError' if I add the full path FFMPEG_BIN = "G:\tool\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

Comment: You posted "stream video from raspberry pi to ubuntu PC", but according to your error message it looks like you are using Windows.

Comment: Well that's the issue then! If you could be more specific about **which** file is not found, you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

image array is empty. It looks like the video wasn't read since raw_image is also empty. Make sure that the video is opened and being read.